# paper.js code not running

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I have recently started working with Paper.js . Trying to use javascript directly i can't figure out why code below produces absolutely nothing when its running:

```
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>paper1</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/paper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    window.onload = function() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    paper.setup(canvas);

    var path = new paper.Path();
    path.strokeColor = 'black';            

    var tool = new paper.Tool();

     tool.onMouseDown = function(event) {
           path.add(event.point);               
            }

    paper.view.draw();
    };

</script>

</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>

</body>
```

I would appreciate any idea

**UPDATE**
It works when i remove window.onload. Why is that happen?

Comment: Adding a working demo and not just code usually helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, something *does* show up. Try to click on the uper left most area of the canvas and the lines will show up. But if you click more on the bottom right, you will see that the lines are not added were you click but are shifted.

There seems to be a problem when using the `resize` attribute. Remove it and add the dimensions manually and it will work as inteded:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Nothing happens on my screen even i change the dimentions manually.

Comment: I'm afraid its a resource problem. Note that i'm working in localhost with XAMPP. Do i need something else from copy-paste paper.js folder in my project-folder and targeting paper.js file in my src script?

Comment: I used https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/paperjs/0.10.2/paper-full.min.js and it works. Do you get any error messages in the browser console?

Comment: Nope, i don;t get anything, on chrome and firefox. I downloaded latest version from http://paperjs.org/download/